# 2 problems with my css dropdown navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I created a css top dropdown navigation bar and it is not quite finished yet. There are two problems I have been trying to solve for a while. The first problem is my nav div is either to tall or my 1px right border tab separators aren't reaching down to the bottom. My second problem is my dropdowns aren't showing. My navigation is on this site  http://osweb01.ostech.com.au/ .

Here is the html:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Home</a>
</li>

<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('about us'); ?>/">About Us</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Why OSTech</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Case Study 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Case Study 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Green IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSdesk Intel vPro Technology</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Workstation Innovation</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Consolidation and Centralisation</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">The Green Grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Clean Technologies</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSdesk Remote Management</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('what we do'); ?>/">What We Do</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSdesk</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSguard</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSmon</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSvault & OSclass</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSmail & OShost</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OStrack & OSdms</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSarchive & OSgroup</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSfaq & OShelp</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">OSbill & OScal</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('contact us'); ?>/">Contact Us</a><ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The nav is inside a div that is floated right as well.
Here is the css. I haven't done the hovers yet cause I want to fix these problems first:

```
#nav {
   display: block;
   position:relative;
   border: 1px solid #002799;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   height: 75px;
   width: 470px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   font: Bold 16px Verdana;
   }

#nav ul {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
  }

#nav ul:after {
   content:*.*;
   display:block;
   height: 0px;
   clear:both;
   visibility: hidden;
  }

#nav li {
   list-style: none;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
  }

#nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #121B3E;
    padding: 10px 25px;
   }

#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width:0px;
   }

#nav ul ul li {
    border: 1p solid #121B3E;
    width:100%;
   }

#nav ul ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    font: Bold 16px Verdana;
   }
```

Can someone please help? I am stuck and not sure what to do.

Comment: your website is not opening...

Comment: I can't open it from home either. I can only open it from work. I only realized this last night. I will talk to my boss about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please see your solution here

## nav {

display: block;
position:relative;
border: 1px solid #002799;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #4970E3 0%, #121B3E 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 15px;
height: 40px;
width: 470px;
margin: 0px auto;
font: Bold 16px Verdana;
}

## nav ul {

margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

## nav ul li {

list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

## nav ul li:last-child a {

```
border:none;
```

}

## nav ul li a {

```
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
border-right: 1px solid #121B3E;
padding: 10px 15px;
```

}

## nav ul ul {

```
display: none;  
position:absolute;
left:0px;
white-space:nowrap;
```

}

## nav ul li:hover ul {

```
display:block;
```

}

## nav ul ul li {

```
border: 1p solid #121B3E;
width:100%;
float:none;
white-space:nowrap;
```

}

## nav ul ul li a {

```
border-right: none;
font: Bold 16px Verdana;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/nponnen/mM9Z5/

Comment: Ok thanks for that. The dropdowns are working now. There is no background color in the dropdowns as well. I tried adding bg color to either nav ul ul li or nav ul ul li a and it doesn't cover all the sub category text in the dropdowns. How do I fix this?

Comment: add background color for nav ul ul {background:red;}

Comment: Still not covering all the subcategory text. I think the text is going outside the width of each ul dropdown. I need to extend it somehow. What do I need to change?

Comment: I tried changing the width of the ul ul and ul ul li but it doesn't seem to be changing. Do you need to change the with of ul ul li a for the width to change in the dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This **[LabDemo](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/previewProject/ienvjr3M8imV27xN5fDu2PzRfLDos9kM)**

To show Sub menu you need to add below `CSS`

```
#nav ul li:hover ul  {
    display:block; 
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

**CSS And HTML** Can be found [**Here**](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/ienvjr3M8imV27xN5fDu2PzRfLDos9kM)

I Will Update my answer with codes once you found it OK :)

Comment: drop menus are showing but dropdown text is going going outside dropdown ul width.